# Writing an add method for an implementation of a doubly linked list that sorts as I add objects to it

Tags: java, list, sorting

Basically as stated, I have my own implementation of a doubly linked list and I want it to sort the objects as they are added using compareTo methods.

```
public void add(E c)
{
Node<E> finger = head;
while (finger != null && ((finger.value().compareTo(c)) > 0))
    finger = finger.Next();


if(finger != null && finger.Next() != null && finger.Previous() != null)
{
    Node<E> n = new Node<E>(c);
    n.setPrev(finger);
    n.setNext(finger.Next());
    finger.Next().setPrev(n);
    finger.setNext(n);
    count++;
}
else if(finger !=null && finger.Next() == null && finger.Previous() != null)
    this.addLast(c);
else if(finger !=null && finger.Next() != null && finger.Previous() == null)
    this.addFirst(c);
else{this.addFirst(c);}     
}
```

I then run

```
DList<String> DD = new DList<String>();
DD.add("d");
DD.add("e");
DD.add("f");
DD.add("a");
DD.add("b");
DD.add("c");
DD.add("g");
DD.add("h");

for(int i = 0; i < DD.size();i++)
    System.out.print(DD.get(i));
```

and the output is hgcbafed.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger to see what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

```
Node<E> finger = head;
if(null == head){
    head = new Node<E>(c);
    return;
}

while (finger.next != null && ((finger.value().compareTo(c)) > 0))
    finger = finger.Next();    
Node n = new Node<E>(c);
n.next = finger.next;//n.setNext(finger.getNext();
finger.next = n;//finger.setNext(n);
```